# How can I open page in my Xamarin app without using navigation?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, .net-core

I have a Xamarin Forms application, which has 2 buttons on the toolbar. Currently I'm using FreshMVVM (and it's navigation). I want to load pages without putting them into the navigation. I do not want to have the 'back' button on the toolbar, also I do not want the user return the last page.

Here's how I push a page currently:

```
CoreMethods.PushPageModel<FirstChoicePageModel>();
```

I tried to push as a modal, but that way the toolbar buttons does not work until I press back. Should I make new navigation containers and switch to them if I push the buttons?

Comment: i think you can achieve by rendering contentview in your content page,  the content page will act as a container for your contentview page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a little while since I've used FreshMVVM, but if I recall correctly, you have 2 options:

1. If you want to completly reset the nav stack, you can do `CoreMethods.PushPageModelWithNewNavigation<FirstChoicePageModel>();`
2. If you want to keep the nav stack, you can set `NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);` in the code behind of the view.

For both of these options, it may necessary to intercept the back button on Android. In the code behind there is an overrideable method:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    return true; // prevent Xamarin.Forms from processing back button
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I did the first suggestion, but I'm now confused.
The back button from the toolbar is gone, that's nice.
But I can go back to the previous page with the physical back button. I don't want that. Why can I go back to previous navigation stack?
(Also, I think there is some mistake in my understanding of nav stacks.)

Comment: @Laszlo I'm not sure why the nav stack is still there. Like I said, it's been a while since I used that framework. See my edit though about the Android back button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a page, but you doesn't want to navigate (change the current page), you can always use Popups.

See this link https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: Thanks, I will use this if I can't solve this problem.